# blocked threads on hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I done research performance, using JProfiler (testing TomCat + hibernate + postgres) . I have the following problem:

I ran two types of queries. Each type of request - at the same time I started the 600 units

Test results:

**The first type of request:**

1) query time 1 ms

2) number of hibernate queries = 500;

3) number of postgresql queries = 150;

4) the CPU usage = 15%

5) **blocked threads = 0**

**The second type of request:**

1) query time 4 ms

2) number of hibernate queries = 260;

3) number of postgresql queries = 300-400;

4) the CPU usage = 30%

5) **blocked threads = 260**

Help, I don't know what to do and what is the cause of block..

the error text:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
connection
```

second  type of queries in the screenshot

[image]

The sequence of work with Hibernate (second type queries)

```
1) session = getFactory().openSession();

2) transaction = session.beginTransaction();

- session.update()

- session.delete()

3) transaction.commit();

4) transaction = session.beginTransaction();

- session.update()

- session.delete()

5) transaction.commit();

6) session.close();
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the queries and how do you run them.

Comment: @dcernahoschi - I updated, please see it

Comment: It's likely that you're failing to close the connection properly. Can you please show more of the code, including how you open and close the session.

Comment: @artbristol - - I updated sequence of work with Hibernate, please see it

Comment: Do you have multiple threads?  Is each thread updating and deleting a single entity?  Do you have any queries in your second type queries?

Comment: @Pace - 1) 600 Request = 600 HttpServlet thred 2) Yes (The sequence of work with Hibernate in my post) 3) no

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Connected `hibernate-c3p0`  - no error